# Finding Lorentz Factor ($\gamma$) with observed Time and Stationary Length

Tags: special-relativity

I've recently come across a problem when deriving a value for the Lorentz Factor, say a length/distance is given from a stationary observer (say the Earth) to a point in space (A Star some light years away). If the time observed on board a spaceship to reach this point was known, could the Lorentz Factor ($\gamma$) be found?

A question regarding this would be similar to the following, (Hope this makes sense)

> The distance to a particular star, as measured in the earth’s frame of
>   reference, is 6.3 ly A spaceship leaves Earth headed for the star, and takes 2.5 yr
>   to arrive, as measured by passengers on the ship.

Comment: Can you draw a position-vs-time graph of the problem? Does the diagram remind of a trigonometry problem? (The Lorentz Factor plays a role similar to cosine.)

Comment: You need the metric to solve this problem